# Kubernetes Ingress - Application login issue when terminating ssl

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I'm using Nginx controller for terminating ssl at ingress level. The application pod is plain http according to the documentation. But during login process there is a `301 internal redirect` from http to https. As a result login never succeeds.

Login POST request succeeds but after the redirect the session is lost and I'm requested to enter username and password again and again.

Any idea what's causing this redirect? I'm not sure if its the Ingress controller issue or if the issue is due to a application redirect.

```
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - appProtocol: http
    name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http # This is so it terminates ssl traffic
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot: 2

[image]

Screenshot 3:

[image]

Comment: is there any rediect at code level? can you also paste screenshot of request header if it from nginx or or application

Comment: Is there a way to configure your application to let it know what protocol / hostname clients are accessing it from?  I've seen a few apps or platforms that require you to specify how clients are accessing them to generate proper redirects.